# No button to ask a question on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, asking-questions, stackexchange.com

I want to post a riddle (or rather, a paradox I cannot seem to explain) to Stack Exchange – yet, there is no button for me to ask a question:

> [image]

This is by far not the first time posting anything online. I have been posting many topics on Stack Overflow but Stack Exchange seems to be too much on my mind.

**Where is the Ask Question button?**

Comment: Which page are you looking at? Could you include the link?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes on this question? Fair but simple question with a simple answer...

Comment: well, this is something I have been observing in all stack forums. Some things are just bound to be downvoted. My teacher once said: there are no stupid questions, only questions that have an answer and stupid answers. I dont believe my quesions is either ;) but thanks for noticing.

Comment: @topomorto: Probably because it takes some reading between the lines to realize that the OP is trying the bare stackexchange.com domain, which most folks on meta have long since internalized as a special case that doesn't "count".

Comment: @innomotionmedia: By the way, for future reference, SE philosophy pretty thoroughly rejects the idea that there are no stupid questions. There are a lot of stupid questions, and most of them get thrown away in various ways with as little fuss as possible.

Comment: @NathanTuggy to complicate the matter: A person that asks a questions has only one purpose: To understand the world better. And even though the answer may have been right at his feet - it is our responsibilty to repeat it over and over again until even the last person (which in this case would be myself) understands even the simplest matter. This way we all benefit from increased overall knowledge. Also, "stupid" lies in the eye of the beholder, doesnt it? However a questions remains a questions and isnt relative. Anyway - good day, sir!

Comment: This question is not stupid. But it's trivial, you [said yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308916/no-button-to-ask-a-qustion-on-stack-exchange#comment1006705_308917): "that is pretty much what I expected". So yes, downvote based on that is legit and expected, as a way to "educate" the asker. That said, "Ask Question" can be added to stackexchange.com where it will open some guided tour helping the user ask in the proper site. (e.g. analyze the title for key words, based on that suggest several sites to choose from.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is trying to do something the site isn't supposed to do

Comment: @RoryAlsop so what? What makes it off topic? This is valid support question. Maybe trivial, it doesn't justify closing, in my opinion.

Comment: That's cool @shad. It does in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) is *not* a site where you can post any question, even though it shows questions from all sites in the network. Instead, you should post questions on the site where they belong, for example on [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) if it's a real [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/riddle/info). A paradox could be [mathematical](https://math.stackexchange.com) or related to [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com), those have their own sites as well. Be sure to read the help center of each site (/help/on-topic) before posting your question.

Comment: Okay, that is pretty much what I expected. Thanks a lot :)